# How to do the filtering in a pipe of a resolver in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8, angular-resolver

In my routes.ts I have `{ path: 'members', component: MemberListComponent, resolve: { users: MemberListResolver} },`.

I have the following piece of code in my component:

```
  users: User[];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data) => {
      this.users = data.users.filter((u: User) => u.id !== +this.authService.decodedToken.nameid);
    });
  }
```

I'm doing the filter in the subscribe method, is it also possible to do this in a pipe, if so how would I do it?

Comment: Using themap operator: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JB Nizet's comment I solved it like:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data
      .pipe(map(data => data.users.filter((u: User) => u.id !== +this.authService.decodedToken.nameid)))
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.users = data;
      });
  }
```